# Algoritmo para (A+Bi)^n

Tags: c, algoritmo

Preciso fazer um programinha que dado a fórmula : A + B*i ^ n 
Tem que achar o menor valor de n para que seja um número real

Sendo A e B entradas e i faz parte dos números complexos.

Tenho um esboço :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
  int a,b,c,n;
  int I  = sqrt(-1);
  scanf("%d",&a);
  scanf("%d",&b);

  for(n=1;n<=30;n++){
    c = pow(a + (b * **I**),n);
    if (c==**Número Real**) 
      printf("Valor de N é: %d",n);         
      break;   
    }
    return 0;   
  }
}
```

Onde está "Número Real" não sei como representar isso codificamente e a Raíz Quadrada de -1 teria que ser i porém da um número absurdo. E eu preciso desse i para fazer a equação.

Comment: Há a [macro `complex`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_mathematical_functions#Complex_numbers) em C e o [pacote `std::complex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/) em C++, que permitem essa representação em termos da parte real e imaginária. Já tentou utilizar? E, aliás, segundo a definição, o seu número resultante vai ser real se a parte imaginária for zero.

Comment: Tentei usar porém não consegui separar os termos ( Parte real e imaginária ) . Exato vai ser real se  a parte imaginária for zero. Mas não consigo codificar isso . Sendo que preciso descobrir qual valor de n para que o imaginário zere.

Comment: Pois então, é por isso que a sua pergunta já recebeu votos pra fechar. Não está claro se a sua dúvida é sobre matemática (fora do escopo do site) ou programação (dentro do escopo do site). Se você já tentou usar (não parece, pelo código que você postou), por que não conseguiu separar os termos? Onde está dando erro? Ou seja, qual é a dúvida específica? Edite a pergunta pra tentar melhorá-la nesse sentido.

Comment: Um exemplo de uso da macro em C: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Complex_floating_types

Comment: é (a + b * i) ^ n? ou só o i?

Comment: Provavelmente entendi mal a pergunta... `#include <stdio.h> main(){printf("0\n");}` (ok não estou a ajudar nada...)

Answer (score 8):

Na verdade sua duvida se torna mais um conceito matemático do que um conceito de programação. Para trabalhar com potências complexas utilize a forma trigonométrica ou a forma de Euler. Não precisa se preocupar com o valor de "i", já que existe, na própria matemática, notação que não o utiliza, como (real, imaginário), notação que trata o número como um par ordenado do plano complexo. O "i" é uma representação que separa a parte real da complexa, não necessita ser trabalhado.

**Código: (resposta para (a + b * i)^n)** 
Comentários no código o explicam (supondo n real):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h> 

#define PI 3.1415926535

/* Estrutura para forma complexa cartesiana */
typedef struct complexCart {

    double real;
    double imaginario;

} ComplexCart; 

/* Estrutura para forma complexa trigonométrica */
typedef struct complexTrig {

    double raio;
    double angulo;

} ComplexTrig;

/* Converte complexo cartesiano para trigonométrico */
ComplexTrig converterTrig(ComplexCart);

/* Converte complexo trigonométrico para cartesiano*/
ComplexCart converterCart(ComplexTrig);

int main(void)
{
    /* Variável que irá armazenar a menor potência 
       necessária. */
    double menorPot;

    /* Variável "cart" irá guardar número na forma
       cartesiana: a + bi, já "trig" na forma trigono-
       métrica: r(cos(Angulo) + i sen(Angulo)). 
       Vale notar que basta trabalhar com os parâmetros 
       em cada um desses casos, por exemplo, para trabalhar
       com dados cartesianos basta (a, b) e trigonométrico sim-
       plesmente (r, Angulo) */
    ComplexCart cart;
    ComplexTrig trig;

    printf("\nDigite um número imaginário da forma a + bi: ");
    /* Espera receber o número da forma cartesiana. 
       Ex: -2 + 3i, ou 2 + -3i (imaginária negativa) */
    scanf("%lf + %lfi", &cart.real, &cart.imaginario);

    /* Converte para forma trigonométrica, essa é mais fácil de lidar 
       com potências, raízes, divisões e multiplicações. Também poderia 
       ser utilizada a forma de Euler */
    trig = converterTrig(cart);

    /* Mostra a forma trigonométrica com o ângulo em radianos: Somente quando
       for exibir o resultado se preocupe com a forma de escrita complexa! */
    printf("O número em forma trigonométrica (em radianos): z = %.2f(cos(%.2f)   + i sen(%.2f))\n", 
         trig.raio, trig.angulo, trig.angulo);  

    /* Com o ângulo calcula-se a menor potência necessária 
       para que a parte do seno zere, ou seja, quando o ângulo é */
    menorPot = PI / (trig.angulo) ;

    /* Mostra a potência e o ângulo final quando a forma trigonométrica
       possui tal ângulo. */
    printf("A menor potência para tornar o número somente real é: %.2f\n", menorPot);
    printf("Ângulo da forma trigonométrica: %.2f rad\n", (trig.angulo) * menorPot); 

    /* Reatribui à forma trigonométrica o valor com a potência, ou seja,
       a forma já será com o valor elevado à potência */
    trig.raio = pow((trig.raio), menorPot);
    trig.angulo = (trig.angulo) * menorPot;

    /* Converte a forma trigonométrica da potência à forma cartesiana */
    cart = converterCart(trig);

    /* Mostra o resultado trigonométrico, o seno do ângulo dev ser zero. 
       Verifique!*/
    printf("Forma trigonométrica z^(%.2f) = %.2f(cos(%.2f) + i sen(%.2f))\n",
        menorPot, trig.raio, trig.angulo, trig.angulo); 

    /* Aqui, na fomra cartesiana, por garantia mostra-se a parte imaginária, 
       que deverá sempre ser zero. */  
    printf("Forma cartesiana z^(%.2f) = %.2f + %.2f i\n\n", menorPot, cart.real,
        cart.imaginario);  

    return 0;
}

/* Implementações dos Protótipos. */
ComplexTrig converterTrig(ComplexCart dadoCart){

    ComplexTrig dadoTrig;

    dadoTrig.raio = sqrt( (dadoCart.real) * (dadoCart.real) +
        (dadoCart.imaginario) * (dadoCart.imaginario) );

    if(dadoCart.real != 0)  
        dadoTrig.angulo = atan( (dadoCart.imaginario) / (dadoCart.real));

    else 
        dadoTrig.angulo = PI / 2;

    return dadoTrig;
}

ComplexCart converterCart(ComplexTrig dadoTrig){

    ComplexCart dadoCart;

    dadoCart.real = (dadoTrig.raio) * cos(dadoTrig . angulo);
    dadoCart.imaginario = (dadoTrig.raio) * sin(dadoTrig.angulo);

    return dadoCart;
}
```

No exemplo acima utilizei estruturas para idealizar melhor (e demonstrar união) do par complexo. (Poderia ter sido feito com 4 doubles independentes, mas com estrutura fica mais fácil visualizar). O resto é matemática. Lembre-se que sempre que for trabalhar com números complexos não é necessário (na maioria das vezes) lidar com o VALOR de i, basta trabalhar como um par ordenado usual, mas sujeito a certa álgebra (Não vou comentar pois sai do escopo do site).

Comment: Resposta realmente muito boa. Parabéns! :)

Comment: Corrigido o caso 0 + 0i, que anteriormente dava erro.

Answer (score 3):

A resposta do Rafael resolve o problema da forma mais esperta (convertendo o complexo para uma representação trigonométrica), mas acho que seria interessante mostrar que não é difícil resolver o problema de uma forma parecida com o que você já tem.

Tudo que você precisa fazer é implementar a multiplicação você mesmo ao invés de tentar querer por números complexos em C e usar o operador `*` nativo.

Se você tiver dois números `X = a + b*i` e `Y = c + d*i` o produto `X*Y` vai ser

```
X*Y =
(a + b*i)(c + d*i)        =  (por distributividade)
ac + ad*i + bc*i + ad*i^2 = (por i^2 = -1)
(ac - bd) + (ad + bc)*i
```

Podemos representar isso em C usando um par de inteiros `(a,b)` para representar o número complexo `a + b*i`.

```
typedef struct {
    int r; /* parte real */
    int i; /*parte imaginaria */
} Complex;
```

E podemos implementar as operações sobre o tipo complexo que acabamos de criar como funções simples ao invés de operadores.

```
Complex addComplex(Complex x, Complex y){
    Complex z;
    z.r = x.r + y.r;
    z.i = x.i + y.i
    return z;
}

Complex multComplex(Complex x, Complex y){
     Complex z;
     z.r = x.r*y.r - x.i*y.i;
     z.i = x.r+y.i + x.i+y.r;
     return z;
}
```

Depois disso, fica fácil implementar uma versão que funciona do código que você já tem:

```
int main(){

    Complex x;
    scanf("%d",&x.r);
    scanf("%d",&x.i);

    Complex x_n = {1, 0};
    for(int n=1;n<=30;n++){
        x_n = multComplex(x_n, x);
        if (x_n.i == 0){
            printf("Valor de N é: %d",n);         
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Uma vantagem de escrever o código dessa forma é que todas as contas são feitas em inteiros ao invés de doubles, o que evita problemas de arredondamento. No entanto, os campos de `x_n` vão sofrer overflow após poucas iterações devido ao crescimento exponencial do "raio" de `x_n`. Uma versão mais robusta desse código deve representar os números complexos com um tipo de dados para "inteiros de precisão infinita" ao invés de usar `int`.

Comment: Mas números complexos podem ser quebrados: a + ib , "a" e "b" são pertencentes aos reais, pois o conjunto dos reais deve estar contido no dos complexos.

Comment: A entrada dele é sempre inteira portanto ele só precisa tratar dos números reais com partes inteiras (inteiros de Gauss).

Comment: Mas assim nunca vai dar o resultado, esse "n" tem que ser float ou double, mesmo que "a" e "b" seja inteiros. Nem sempre o expoente será inteiro. Se você testa será raro algum resultado bater, e se bater será truncado. Por exemplo: 2 + 3i, o expoente será 3.2, mesmo com "a" e "b" sendo inteiros. Além disso testei no seu código 2 e 3, por exemplo, e nada mostrou (não alcançou o if), talvez devido a esse problema.

Comment: Dado o for da pergunta inicial eu assumi "menor n inteiro" ao invés de "menor n". São duas interpretações diferentes da pergunta

Comment: Embora seja uma interpretação possivel e a tua solução interessante, dá-me ideia que n inteiro muito raramente terá solução.

Comment: Bem, se esse fosse o caso, pode ser impossível achar um dado n inteiro para "a" e "b" fornecidos pelo usuário (como @JJoao) falou. Nada garante que ele seja inteiro, mesmo com potências maiores, inclusive variando até o infinito, ou seja, pode ficar sem solução. Além disso a própria definição de número complexo utiliza o termo "real" justamente por cair no conjunto dos reais quando a parte imaginária é zero.

Comment: Terá solução quando o ângulo phi for da forma pi*fracionário; caso contrário não tem solução (por definição de imaginário). Teremos que escolhar a e b cuidadosamente. Ainda assim gosto da solução (+1)

Comment: O problema é o usuário escolher a e b, será praticamente um jogo de loteria. Seria interessante um programa em que o usuário digitar a (ou b) e daí sim para calcular b e n inteiros.